# Constructor in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am in react.js. I am learning react.js. I would like to know when to use `constructor` like below and when not.

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) Initialising `state`**

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(props) {

        // when you want to iniitialize state
        // (ex. below is setting initial value for 'inputBoxValue')
        this.state = {
            inputBoxValue: 'initial value',
        };
    }
}
```

**2) Using `this` in `constructor`**

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(props) {

        // when you want to use `this` in `constructor`
        // super needs to be called first
        super();


        // that means, when you want to use `this.props`
        // in `constructor`, call it like below
        super(props);
    }
}
```

**3) Providing `ref` callback for accessing DOM**

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(props) {

        // when you want to create ref
        this.myElementRef = (ref) => {
            this.myElement = ref;
        };
    }
}
```

**5) Initializing Third-party libraries**

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(props) {

        // initialize third party libs, primarily non react libs
        this.myHelper = new MyHelperLibrary();


        // note: you can still access props without using `this`
        this.myHelper2 = new MyHelperLibrary(props.environment);
    }
}
```

**4) Binding some context(`this`) in case you want class method to be passed in `props` to `children`.**

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(props) {

        // when you want to `bind` context to a function
        this.myFunction = this.myFunction.bind(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have no useful things of your own to do in the constructor, then you don't need one.

Examples of useful things include:

- setting initial state based on the initial props
- binding functions to `this`

The constructor in the question is what would happen by default, if you didn't write one of your own. So if you have no lines of your own to add, then you can safely remove it from your component class.

Answer (score 2):

In a React component, constructor is used to **initialize the state**. It's the right place to do it.

When implementing constructor for a react component which derived from React.Component, **super** method should be called.

For more detailed information, I suggest to look for this React document: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

Answer (score 1):

Assuming below React Component tree

```
 <A>
   <B dataProps={this.state.data}/>
 </A>
```

`this.state.data` is getting passed component to component B from parent component A.

Now,incomponent B,if you want to access `this.state.data`,you need to use

`this.props.dataProps`

Coming to your constructor quetition,

**case 1 :**

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
}
```

in this case,
`console.log(this.props.dataProps)` will log `dataProps` mapped to `this.state.data` because 
`this.props` initilised with `props` coming from parent component `A` i.e. `dataProps` value for `this.state.data`

**case 2:**

assume in constructor, there is call to only `super()` without `props`.

```
constructor() {
   super();
}
```

In this case,
`console.log(this.props.dataProps) //undefined bcause this.props is undefined`

Answer (score 0):

When you are getting the props from the parent component and you are using these props in the constructor to initialize the state then you have to use the syntax:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
}
```

And if you are not using the props to initialize the state then you can use the syntax:

```
constructor() {
   super();
}
```